# Configuring form_path in Catalyst::Controller::Formbuilder

Tags: perl, catalyst

Using the `Catalyst::Controller::FormBuilder` module to handle forms in a Catalyst application.

The documentation says you can set the form_path like this:

`form_path => File::Spec->catfile( $c->config->{home}, 'root', 'forms' )`,

But the call to config() in my application is at the top level of the base module. Therefore, $c is undefined. So I can't call $c->config->{home}.

What is the proper way to configure **form_path** please?

Comment: `AppName->path_to(qw/root forms/)`?

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, good answer. This works:

form_path => File::Spec->catfile(AppName->path_to(qw'etc forms')),

I moved the forms, templates, and config to etc out of root. I found that I could get copies of templates etc by going to http://example.com/forms/search/page.fb for example. I didn't like that, so I cleared the stuff out of root so that doesn't happen any more.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access configuration values that have already been set from your application's main module using the `__PACKAGE__->config` hash.  Example: `__PACKAGE__->config->{home}` or `__PACKAGE__->config->{'Controller::FormBuilder'}->{form_path}`.

If you're trying to set the FormBuilder configuration in your applications main module, you should be able to use the code provided in the documentation and just replace `$c->config->{home}` with `__PACKAGE__->config->{home}`.  I think they might have even made a mistake by not doing it this way, but I'm not sure.